# iOS - How to change properties of root navigation controller from a pushed controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller with a root view controller that is WAViewController that it push WAInfoViewController passing to it some values. Now I use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to turn back and I want to restore the values changed in WAInfoController in WAViewController. How can I do it?

I guess if I create a reference to WAViewController like so I get wrong because it is already initialized

```
WAViewController *controller = [[WAViewController alloc]init];
controller.properties = VALUES;
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers guys. The problem is that in the topViewController I init an audio guide with play/pause buttons. When I go in info-page (the pushed view controller), I init the new synthesizer and the new utterance with the values of the topViewController so the audio guide will continue. Well, when I go back, the audio guide stops and it doesn't work no more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways. You could use delegation, which is probably the best way to do it -- you would create a delegate protocol in the WAInfoViewController, and the WAViewController would set itself as the delegate when it does the push. Before you do the pop back to WAViewController, you would call the delegate method to do what ever you need to do.

The other way, which is easier, would be to get a reference to the navigation controller's root view controller using its topViewController property.

```
WAViewController *controller = self.navigationController.topViewController;
controller.properties = VALUES;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. The problem is that in the topViewController I init an audio guide with play/pause buttons. When I go in info-page (the pushed view controller), I init the new synthesizer and the new utterance with the values of the topViewController so the audio guide will continue. Well, when I go back, the audio guide stops and it doesn't work no more

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this via exit segues. You define an exit segue in WAViewController as

```
-(void)nameOfExitSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue {
   WAInfoViewController* controller = segue.sourceViewController;

   // Get changed values and do something with them.
}
```

In storyboard, you can hook up the action of the UI element you want to dismiss WAInfoVIewController to the exit segue icon. When you control-drag the line to the Exit Segue icon, you will see your exit segue methods pop up. Just select the exitSegue method you made.